# Update IPS to security group aws

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services

I am trying to update my security group of aws using a shell script. Here is my code.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 Ip=$1
 #rotocol=$1
 port=$1
 aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-id --protocol tcp --
 port $port --cidr $Ip
```

I am receiving the following error while running the script.

> port parameter should be of the form  (e.g. 22 or 22-25)

How to update the security group using the shell?

Comment: I think you need to change `port=$1` to `port=$2` and send port number as second argument to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
Ip=$1
port=$2
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-id --protocol tcp --port $port --cidr $Ip
```

This should do the trick. You cannot have the same variable for Ip and Port, adding a second parameter for port will resolve your issue.

Comment: still getting the same error     "port parameter should be of the form <from[-to]> (e.g. 22 or 22-25)"

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have passed the parameter wrongly its working fine now.

Comment: What if we want to update an existing IP from the security group? The above script would add the IPs, not update existing.